# take date from datetime, to string then integrate with API python

Tags: python, pandas, google-api-python-client, data-processing

so I want to integrate my code with python API

```
# Install required library
!pip install xlrd
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time, timedelta, datetime
import openpyxl
import math
!pip install pytanggalmerah
from pytanggalmerah import TanggalMerah

# Mount google drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Read the Excel file
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Book2.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(path)


# Convert the 'Tgl/Waktu' column to datetime format
df['Tgl/Waktu'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Tgl/Waktu'])

# Extract the date and time from the 'Tgl/Waktu' column
df['Date'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.date
a = df['Date'].drop_duplicates()

print(a)
```

with that code, it will have output as

```
0     2022-12-17
2     2022-12-19
4     2022-12-20
6     2022-12-21
8     2022-12-22
10    2022-12-23
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

and for the API i will use [pytanggalmerah](https://github.com/guangrei/pytanggalmerah) which will need the input to be

```
t.set_date("2019", "02", "05") #the order is Year, Month, Date
t.check()
```

how do i change my date object into string then make a for loop with my string to check whether is it true or false

how do i do it? how to integrate it?

Comment: or probably how do i use if else using datetime format
with [the holidays data](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cUqLHguVfEpPt8YFwz_DYjvrX_RRdqK56eqJlColWcc/edit?usp=sharing) can you guys give an example to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comp:

```
dates = [(str(x.year), str(x.month), str(x.day)) for x in df["Tgl/Waktu"].unique().tolist()]
for date in dates:
    year, month, day = date
    t.set_date(year, month, day)
```

is_holiday question:

```
import numpy as np


holidays = pd.DataFrame(holiday_data).rename(columns={"Date": "Day"})

cols = ["Year", "Month", "Day"]
holidays = holidays.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(holidays[cols]).dt.date).drop(columns=cols)

df["is_holiday"] = np.where(df["Tgl/Waktu"].isin(holidays["Date"].to_list()), True, False)
print(df)
```

Comment: how to make it into a new column named 'is_holidays' with true and false value?

Comment: well holiday in which country? And if US do you want Federal Holidays or all holidays?

Comment: [this holiday data](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cUqLHguVfEpPt8YFwz_DYjvrX_RRdqK56eqJlColWcc/edit?usp=sharing), with your answer above it doesnt work, probably you know how to make if else statement of datetime, if the date is equal to the ones in holiday data give it true value, if not then make it false

Comment: see edit. Not sure how you are reading the holiday data but I used a dictionary in this case.